# There are no primary key or candidate key error .. what should I do .. I hava uploaded two pic to see the errors clearly

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

Below is the `CREATE` script for all those tables

Table `schools` schema

```
CREATE TABLE schools
 (
     NAME          VARCHAR(20),
     levell        VARCHAR(20),
     adress        VARCHAR(20),
     main_language VARCHAR(20),
     email         VARCHAR(20),
     information   VARCHAR(80),
     mission       VARCHAR(80),
     vision        VARCHAR(80),
     type          VARCHAR(20),
     fees          REAL,
     phone_number  INT,
     PRIMARY KEY (NAME, levell)
  )
```

Table `school_phones` schema

```
CREATE TABLE school_phones
  (
     NAME         VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
     phone_number INT,
     FOREIGN KEY (NAME, phone_number) REFERENCES schools
  ) 
--phone.name references school
```

Table `elementary_schools` schema

```
CREATE TABLE elementary_schools
(
  NAME   VARCHAR(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES schools(NAME) ,
  levell VARCHAR(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES schools(levell) ,
  PRIMARY KEY(NAME , levell)
)
--elementary.name references school
```

Table `elementary_school_supplies` schema

```
CREATE TABLE elementary_school_supplies
  (
     NAME     VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES elementary_schools(
     NAME),
     supplies VARCHAR(20)
  ) 
--Elementary_Schools.name references elementary
```

Table `middle_schools` schema

```
CREATE TABLE middle_schools
  (
     NAME VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES schools
  ) 
--middle.name references school
```

Table `high_schools` schema

```
CREATE TABLE high_schools
  (
     NAME VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES schools
  )
```

The errors are displayed in the below pictures

Error1:
[image]

Error2:
[image]

Any help to solve this would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: could you please have a look at the error in the picture that i have uploaded ... I have tried many ways to write the foreign and primary key in the above code but i failed .. you can see that i have used there more than one syntax to write it but i couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is that your PK on Schools is a composite of `name` and `levell`. You're trying to reference these with separate `FK's`, you need a composite `FK` too.

You want to do the same thing that you've done with the School_Phones table, something like this;

```
CREATE TABLE Elementary_Schools (name varchar(20), levell varchar(20), primary key (name, levell), foreign key (name, levell) references Schools)
```

The second issue is pretty self explanatory, you can only `FK` fields of the same data type. Your `phone_number` field (`int`) cannot reference `levell` as it's a `varchar(20)`. These need to both be the same data type.